# 3 column grid layout, full screen

Tags: css

I am new to `grid`. I want it fullscreen, but, not sure. Also not sure, of why the `navigator` and `sidebar`
appear as they appear.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 200px;
    grid-template-rows: auto 2fr auto;
    grid-template-areas:
    "header header  header"
    "nav    article aside"
    "footer footer  footer";
    grid-column-gap: 8px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

header, nav, footer, main, article, aside 
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

header {
    background-color: bisque;
    grid-area: header;
}

nav {
    grid-area: nav;
}

aside {
    grid-area: side;
}

article {
    grid-area: article;
    background-color: aqua;
}

footer{
    background-color: beige;
    width: 100%;
    grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/base.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" role="main">
        <header>{header}</header>
        <nav>{navigation}</nav>
        <article>
            <main>{main content}</main>
        </article>
        <aside>{sidebar}</aside>
        <footer>{footer}</footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D, please see edit now. I am sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 200px;
    grid-template-rows: auto 2fr auto;
    grid-template-areas:
    "header header  header"
    "nav    article aside"
    "footer footer  footer";
    grid-column-gap: 8px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

header, nav, footer, main, article, aside 
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

header {
    background-color: bisque;
    grid-area: header;
}

nav {
    grid-area: nav;
}

aside {
    grid-area: aside;
}

article {
    grid-area: article;
    background-color: aqua;
}

footer{
    background-color: beige;
    width: 100%;
    grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/base.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" role="main">
        <header>{header}</header>
        <nav>{navigation}</nav>
        <article>
            <main>{main content}</main>
        </article>
        <aside>{sidebar}</aside>
        <footer>{footer}</footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have an error on the rule `aside`, shoul be `aside { grid-area: aside;}`

Comment: Luis P.A, thank you, this was fast. How can I control the sizes of `footer` and `header`? Is, it just to update the element itself, or the column properties?

Comment: You should not fix the header and the footer, they will be adapted by the second row (1fr). But if you want you shoul give the values in the `grid-template-rows`

Comment: Luis P.A., I sorted that out, thank you so much. ;-)

Comment: I basically, modified their heights separately. ;-)